# how to fix broken sudoers file without root

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo, sudoers, visudo

How to fix broken sudoers file in rhel6, it's not allowing me to get into sudo

```
 [bash ~]$ sudo su
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 109 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 109 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 109
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I cannot edit this file as the permission is not there and this is **virtual machine**

Comment: Access the drive in another system (physically move) so you can bypass permissions and fix syntax of the file from there. If it's a VM you can still attach it to another VM.

Comment: Do you have `pkexec` installed? Try using that instead of `sudo`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1272527/339740

Answer (score 1):

From the redhat [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html)

> What can you do if you forget your root password? To reset it to a
>   different password, boot into rescue mode or single-user mode, and use
>   the passwd command to reset the root password.

then with root access you can fix the sudoers file

Answer (score 1):

I know answering to this question is too late but it might be helpful to someone in the future.

instead of opening with sudo on terminal type `visudo`  and edit the sudoers file.